# What package creates /usr/lib/jvm/default-java?

Tags: 11.10, java

I'm trying to setup Jenkins on 11.10 using only Ubuntu-provided packages. After `apt-get install jenkins`, Jenkins won't start. I traced it to an absent `/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/bin/java`.

```
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                            Version                                 Description
+++-===============================-=======================================-==============================================================================
ii  jenkins                         1.409.1-0ubuntu4.2                      Continuous Integration and Job Scheduling Server
ii  openjdk-6-jre                   6b24-1.11.3-1ubuntu0.11.10.1            OpenJDK Java runtime, using Hotspot JIT

# update-alternative  --config java
There is only one alternative in link group java: /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/bin/java
Nothing to configure.
```

What package creates /usr/lib/jvm/default-java ?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can search for this information using apt-file. You may need to setup apt-file before you can use it.

```
sudo apt-get install apt-file            #Installs
sudo apt-file update                     #Updates local file list
apt-file search <path to file/directory> #Does the searching
```

It reports that `default-jre-headless` is the package you should be looking for.

[You may find this question on Super User useful](https://superuser.com/q/10997/127816)

Comment: It's important to search for the right path, because `/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/bin/java` can't be found, but `/usr/lib/jvm/default-java` can be. Thanks for the detailed answer and the link!